# How to compress the react application in order to publish it as a chrome extension?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, deployment, google-chrome-devtools, publish

- I have been working on a reactJs application as a chrome extension.
- I made it, it works perfectly fine and even I have load unpacked and used as an extension in developer mode.
- But when I am trying to publish it on chrome store, it asks to submit the zip file, but as soon as i submit my react apps zip file it rejects it.
- What should I do.
- The file structure is as follows:
- [image: File structure]
- I tried to zip the entire root directory of my react application and upload it but it gives error as shown below:
- [image: Error Message]

Comment: You need to submit the build, not src.

Comment: So I need to compress the build file that I will get after ```npm run build``` and submit it on chrome web store ??

I would try it once and let you know, thanks for helping.